# Maven replacing resources while building

Tags: java, maven

I have a project with 3 profiles - dev, test, prod. I have also three web.xml versions, stored in cofig/profile_name/WEB-INF/ folder. I have also default version stored in main/webapp/WEB-INF .

My goal is to pick one of theese versions while building depend of selected profile. So if `I pick mvn install -P dev`, maven will replace default xml file in main/webapp/WEB-INF using file from dev folder. If I dot pick any of theese profiles, Maven will use default web.xml.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you take a slightly different approach by defining placeholders in your web.xml file, you can use resource filtering (see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). This is probably a better approach since it will avoid a lot of repetition.

Each of your profile can define a different set of property values for the variables you declare in your web.xml file, and depending on the profile you pass it will result in a different web.xml file.